# Find out the type of a Profobuf message (Google Chrome Sync)

Tags: google-chrome, synchronization, protocol-buffers

I'm trying to connect to Google Chrome sync (that synchronizes your Chrome settings and your currently opened tabs). 
For now I'm concentrating on on the tab syncing. I connected to the Google Talk servers and I'm receiving messages from *tango bot* whenever I navigate to a new webpage in Chrome.

But I have difficulties decoding those messages as they are encodes in Google's protobuf format – because there are tons of different protobuf classes dedicated to Chrome Sync and I think there's no way of figuring out the type of a binary protobuf message?

A typical message would look like this (base64 encoded, XXXX't out my mail adress):

```
CAAilQEKQAoGCgQIAxACEiUKBgoECAMQARISCZwF6dZYmkeFEXZLABNN3/yMGgcIhSwQAxgBINP80ri/JyoIMTgxOTgxMjYaUQpPCgwI7AcSB1NFU1NJT04QARiw64/I0se0AiIyVzpDaGZDeU9JWUZXdXFuUmRXaGtJWk94VkRSM1lmTGU1M0FoRGVxT2EwOHVQUHcyOD0wASoGCgQIAxACMAI4AUIrCG8SJxAEGAIiFGRlbHXXXXXXXXdAZ21haWwuY29tQgl0YW5nb19yYXdIAQ==
```

I tried decoding it with some of the protobuf classes (that I compiled for Java), but with none of them I got any useful data.

Does anyone have more information on this topic? Some insight on how to find the right protobuf class for decoding a certain binary message would be great. It would even help me to some point to be able to decode that exact message I gave as an example above.
There is very little [public documentation](http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/sync) and the Chromium source code is really difficult to look trough if you're not a C++ guy…
(I'm developing in Java, if that matters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is broadly possible; however, it cannot be done with the data you have posted because you have corrupted it irretrievably in your attempt to remove your email address. Protobuf is very sensitive to that; I tried replacing the XXXXXXXX with the base-64 for a 6-letter email-address, but the byte immediate before that is 199, and 199 cannot be legal there (the data immediately before string contents is the length of the string encoded as a varint, and a varint can never end with the most-significant-bit of the last byte set, because the MSB is a continuation flag).

If you have raw protobuf binary, you can try running it through `protoc --decode_raw`, and see what it says; that may give you enough to start reconstructing the layout. Alternatively, you can try parsing it manually with your preferred implementation's "reader" API (if it has one). For example, using protobuf-net and `ProtoReader`, I was able to piece together (the numbers in brackets are the offsets **after** reading each field-header):

```
{
    (1) field 1: varint, value 0 if int
    (3) field 4: string, looks like sub-message
    // everything after this point is really really suspect
        (6) field 1, string, looks like sub-message
            (8) field 1, string, looks like sub-message
            (16) field 2, string, looks like sub-message
            (55) field 4, varint, 1357060030035 assuming int64
            (62) field 5, string; "18198126"
        (72) field 3, string, looks like sub-message
            (64) field 1, string, looks like some encoded session data
    (155) field 5: string, looks like sub-message
        (157) field 1: string, looks like sub-message
    (163) field 6: varint, value 2 if int
    (165) field 7: varint, value 1 if int
    (167) field 8: string, looks like sub-message
        (169) field 1: varint, value 111 if int
        (171) field 2: string, looks like sub-message
}
```

The problem is that due to the corruption (because of your replacement), it is impossible to say much beyond that field 4; by that point, everything could be completely gibberish due to the lengths being off. So I have very little confidence past that point. The main point of the above is simply to illustrate: yes, you can parse protobuf data without knowing the schema in advance, to reverse engineer a schema - but it requires:

- patience and a little guesswork to interpret each field (each wire-type can mean multiple things)

  - if you know what the values being stored, without necessarily knowing how each maps to fields, then you have a headstart; for example, if you know you are being sent something with the values 22, 1325, "hello world", and 123.45F; then you should be able to figure out the mapping easily enough
- intact data (which is sadly missing in this case)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, that helped me a lot! And I'm sorry for corrupting the data, I realized that a bit too late. But I was able to decode it using the _--decode_raw_ flag and it's close to your interpretation! Now I just have to find my way through that sub-sub-sub-message nightmare… Do you know what could be wrong, when protoc fails to decode a message? Because I have some other samples that I can't run through it – but I yet have to try it with offsets in case there's some custom header…

Comment: @florianh decoding without schema is as much an art as a science; I'd probably need to see them, but the first thing that leaps to mind is: "some custom length-prefix formation to separate multiple discreet messages in a single stream"